# HDMI to SCART - Using Mega Drive (Genesis) Mini with CRT

Tags: crt-monitor, sega-genesis, scart

I have a Mega Drive (Genesis) Mini that features an HDMI output that I would like to use on a CRT TV I have with a SCART input.

Ideally I would like to **convert the HDMI to RGB SCART** for the best possible image.

From my searching it seems that this is not a very mainstream conversion and I'd struggled to find a device that will do it - ideally with low latency. I would very much appreciate input from others who have gone down this route and found a suitable solution.

Comment: There should be a question which can be answered. Sure, retro gear has a retro inputs, but you just seem to be asking what HDMI to SCART adapter you should buy to connect a modern device to a retro CRT TV. It really does not matter what the modern HDMI device is.

Comment: You are not going to get a better result using an external DAC (converting the hdmi to analogue) than you would simply using the rgb on the scart input connected to the rgb on the device

Comment: @camelccc The problem is the device has no analog outputs, just HDMI. It's not a retro console. It's basically akin to a Raspberry Pi or other ARM CPU board running Linux and the retro games are run under software emulation.

Comment: Aren't there a ton of hdmi to scart converters out there already? All of them works the same because the chip inside them comes from the same vendor, just like all usb hubs uses VIA's 1-to-4 hub chip.

Comment: How about this https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32822074634.html or this https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004058500007.html ?

Comment: I've not seen good reviews from those cheap devices @Michael Graf, which is what lead me here to see if people had experience of higher quality devices with lower latancy

Comment: I suspect there aren't any. The predominant use case for these converters, I suspect, is to use existing CRT TVs with modern BD/DVD players, satellite/cable receivers, or streaming devices. The main requirement here would be "cheap", given how cheap low-end flat screen TVs have become; latency, on the other hand, does not really matter. Note also that SCART does not imply RGB or S-Video - it might also be just composite Video on Pin 20.